Nodes in different DCs cannot connect to each other in a multi-region cluster
I have a problem setting up a Cassandra nodes in different datacenters.
Each datacenter has public IPs; Let's assume there are 111.111.111.x and 222.222.222.x. Cassandra nodes starts in docker containers - 3 nodes in each DC. The problem is DCs don't see each other.
Here are docker-compose files for first cluster on host with ip 111.111.111.x
version: '3.3'

services:
  cass1:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass1
    hostname: cass1
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "7000:7000"
    environment: &environment
        HEAP_NEWSIZE: 128M
        MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 2048M
        CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cass1, cass2, 222.222.222.222”
        CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: ks
        CASSANDRA_DC: DC1
        CASSANDRA_RACK: West
        CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
        CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS: 256

  cass2:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass2
    hostname: cass2
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9043:9042"
      - "7001:7000"
    environment: *environment
    depends_on:
      - cass1

  cass3:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass3
    hostname: cass3
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9044:9042"
      - "7002:7000"
    environment: *environment
    depends_on:
      - cass2

networks:
  cassandra:

And the second cluster on host with ip 222.222.222.x
version: '3.3'

services:
  cass1:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass1
    hostname: cass1
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "7000:7000"
    environment: &environment
        HEAP_NEWSIZE: 128M
        MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 2048M
        CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cass1, cass2, 111.111.111.111”
        CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: ks
        CASSANDRA_DC: DC2
        CASSANDRA_RACK: East
        CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
        CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS: 256

  cass2:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass2
    hostname: cass2
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9043:9042"
      - "7001:7000"
    environment: *environment
    depends_on:
      - cass1

  cass3:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: cass3
    hostname: cass3
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-e", "describe keyspaces" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    networks:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - "9044:9042"
      - "7002:7000"
    environment: *environment
    depends_on:
      - cass2

networks:
  cassandra:

After startup each cluster is seeing only itself and doesn't see other cluster. For example nodetool status output for 111.111.111.111
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.18.0.4  108.81 KiB  256     60.1%             3ceecd38-0c30-4189-9a52-cb23465ca0ca  West
UN  172.18.0.3  113.77 KiB  256     70.4%             f1f6f63a-7cc5-4883-8b90-5159c6b6613c  West
UN  172.18.0.2  108.74 KiB  256     69.5%             94395942-8efa-447b-9961-2d80375bce35  West

netcat show that another host is available
nc -v 222.222.222.222 7000
Connection to 222.222.222.222 7000 port [tcp/*]
succeeded!

No errors in cassandra logs.
Maybe some misconfiguration has happened? I tried to run 2 DCs on same host and it worked properly with intercommunication between DCs.
TY for answers.

I think you're mixing terminologies in your question. You've confused "data centre" with "cluster". It is dangerous for two different Cassandra clusters to communicate with each other because if that was allowed to happen, both clusters would be rendered inoperable. As such, I'm going to rewrite your question to simply refer to the nodes in the different regions as belonging to separate DCs. Cheers!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

For nodes to form a cluster, three things must be true:

All nodes must have the same cluster_name.
Nodes must have common seeds.
There must be bi-directional network connectivity between all nodes, specifically on the gossip port.

When a node comes online, it will attempt to gossip with a seed node in order to get information about the cluster. If there is no network connectivity with the other nodes, it won't be able to join the cluster.
If a node gossips with another node which has another cluster name, those two nodes will reject each other as they don't belong to the same cluster.
In your case, I suspect the nodes are not able to gossip with each other across regions. Typically on public clouds, nodes cannot communicate with another region over the private IPs so it is necessary to configure the nodes with:
listen_address: private_IP
broadcast_address: public_IP

With this configuration, nodes within the same region would connect on their private IPs but will connect with nodes in another region with their public IPs.
I've also noted from your Docker compose that you've exposed the gossip port (7000) on different ports on the host which means that the nodes won't be able to gossip with the nodes in other regions on port 7000. Cheers!
